# Выявление накруток и блокировка IP адресов пользователей в большой MySQL таблице для голосований

Tags: php, mysql

Прошу помощи в решении задачи. Есть таблица MySQL, в нее записываются голоса пользователей.

В ней более 1 млн записей.

Там хранятся записи:

  -id

  -time()

  -ip пользователя

  (ну и др информация, она нам не понадобится)

Мне нужно определить из этого списка, ip адреса, с которых за период равный 10 часам было сделано 50 и более голосов.

Как это оптимально и правильно сделать? Cистема, которую я набросал, с группировкой и перебором по таблице, убивает мой сервер.

Вот код: (могут быть ошибки, но в целом надеюсь понятно)

```php
$db_query = mysql_query("
    SELECT `ip`
    FROM `mark` 
    GROUP BY `ip`");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($db_query)) {

$d = mysql_query("
    SELECT `time` 
    FROM `mark` 
    WHERE `ip` = ".$row["ip"]
    );
$t = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($d)) {
$t[] = $r["time"];
}

for($i=0; $i<count($t); $i++)
{
$t1 = $t[$i];
if(count($t)<($i+50)) 
$t2 = $t[count($t)];
    else
$t2 = $t[$i+50];

if($t2 - $t1 >= 60*60*10) {echo $row["ip"]; echo '<br/>'; break;}
}
}
```

Comment: покажите своё решение, от него уже будем отталкиваться и думать, как его оптимизировать

Comment: манипуляции с большим массивом данных лучше всё же оставить серверу баз данных. «выгребание» этого массива в любой интерпретатор — по-моему, не самое оптимальное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

из ненакладных для сервера базы данных вариантов пока пришла в голову только группировка по 10-часовым интервалам.

примерно так:

```
select ip, floor(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)/(60*60*10)), count(*)
 from mark
 group by 1,2
 having count(*) > 50;
```

поиск же разницы между значениями в столбце `time`, как я понимаю, требует уже объединения (*join*) таблицы с самой собой, что для большой таблицы весьма ресурсозатратная задача.

это, конечно, не полноценный ответ на вопрос, но, надеюсь, поможет в поиске подходящего решения.

Comment: Спасибо, очень хороший вариант, почти то что нужно! Пока возьму его за основу.

Comment: Нет нужной репутации для этого(

Answer (score 1):

1. Периодически сохраняйте суммарное количество голосов в другой таблице.
2. также проиндексируйте таблицу по дате, тоже помогает.
3. сохраняйте отдельный месяцы в различных таблицах, или после статистики сохраните статистику в другом таблице и удалите старые данные из этой. Можно скопировать старые данные на другую таблицу.